# Postgres COLLATION FOR

Tags: sql, postgresql, collation, postgresql-10

I have tried the function `collation for(argument)` which is described in [the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE). But when I try to execute the query which is given in the same PostgreSQL documentation, I get an error. Actually, the statement that I ran was

```
SELECT collation for ('sample') FROM pg_description LIMIT 1;
```

1. It could be better if someone gives the exact correct query and the correct parameters for the function.
2. What is the use case of this function?
3. If the function name was wrong, please give me the correct function name.

Comment: Please show: The actual query you tried and the verbatim error message you got - as **text**, not as image. And are you really working with outdated Postgres 9.5?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter
Query which I have tried `SELECT collation for ('sample') FROM pg_description LIMIT 1;`

I am working in postgres 10.

Comment: Would still be curious about that error message ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, `COLLATION FOR` is not a "function", but a syntax element of SQL. The underlying function in Postgres is `pg_collation_for()`.

All required information is in the manual, [even for your outdated version Postgres 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-info.html). Search for *"collation for"* on that manual page and you'll find an example with explanation.

But it's more clearly documented in the [current version](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) (quote from pg 15):

> Returns the name of the collation of the value that is passed to it.
> The value is quoted and schema-qualified if necessary. If no collation
> was derived for the argument expression, then NULL is returned. **If
> the argument is not of a collatable data type, then an error is
> raised.**

Bold emphasis mine.

Basically, only string types like `text` and `varchar` are collatable.

No error should happen for the example query from the manual as `pg_description.description` is type `text`. But you ran a different one:

```
SELECT collation for ('sample') FROM pg_description LIMIT 1;
```

Which can be shortened to just:

```
SELECT collation for ('sample');
```

`'sample'` is an untyped string literal, i.e. type "unknonwn", but it will be coerced to `text` by default, so it should not error out, either.